# How to bind zoom event on PDF document with a function in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

A pdf document is there in `iframe` and a rectangular box over it. I want to zoom the box(increase height and width) with same ratio at which page is getting zoomed.

[image]

As the document is shown using adobe plugin, I am not able to capture *zoom* with any event or function. I can't use other plugins i.e ng2-pdf-piewer, pdf.js etc. because of some other limitations.

html -

```
<div id="document">
    <iframe [src]='byPassedFilePath' id="idocument" type="application/pdf" width="100%" [height]='pdfHeight'></iframe>
</div>

<div id="rectangle">
    <iframe id="irectangle"></iframe>
</div>
```

css -

```
#document{
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

#idocument{
    border: none;
}

#rectangle{
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

#irectangle{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Couldn't find anything to relate zoom.